# scala += assignment oddity on string

Tags: scala, concatenation, variable-assignment

I'm trying Scala 2.9 (and I like it!) Consider the following:

```
scala> "hello" += " world"
<console>:8: error: value += is not a member of java.lang.String
         "hello" += " world"
```

And now

```
scala> var h = "hello "
h: java.lang.String = "hello "

scala> h += "world"

scala> h
res24: java.lang.String = hello world
```

I would have thought that both string expressions in the first example would naturally evaluate in order to allow the operation. Is there a good reason for this behavior?

Cheers!

Answer (score 10):

You can't modify a constant.
`"hello"` is constant, `h` isn't.

You're writing

```
"hello" = "hello" + " world"
```

which doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: aha. yes that makes sense. I've been watching collections making copies of themselves all day and didn't think that one through. Cheers!

Comment: actually, your collections quite probably aren't making copies of themselves.  Under the covers, most of the immutable collection classes are implemented with shared state.  It just _looks_ like copies are being made, but is much more efficient

Comment: as for me it looks like h = h + "world", which is quite ok, while h is a var, not val